# getting Y value[Ycbcr] of one Pixel in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get the Y value of pixel from a frame that's in Ycbcr color mode.
here what I' wrote:

```
 cv::Mat frame, Ycbcrframe, helpframe;
 ........ 
cvtColor(frame,yCbCrFrame,CV_RGB2YCrCb); // converting to Ycbcr
Vec3b intensity =yCbCrFrame.at<uchar>(YPoint);
uchar yv  = intensity.val[0]; //  I thought it's my Y value but its not, coz he gives me I think the Blue channel of RGB color space
```

any Idea how what the correct way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about the following code?

```
Vec3f Y_pix = YCbCrframe.at<Vec3f>(rows, cols);
int pixelval = Y_pix[0];
```

(P.S. I havent tried it yet)

Answer (score 0):

You need to know both the depth (numerical format and precision of channel sample) as well as the channel count (typically 3, but can also be 1 (monochrome) or 4 (alpha-containing)), ahead of time.

For 3-channel, 8-bit unsigned integer (a.k.a. byte or `uchar`) pixel format, each pixel can be accessed with

```
mat8UC3.at<cv::Vec3b>(pt);
```